# SKU Construction

Tags: sku

What are the best practices for building SKU identifiers? I was reading on one e-commerce site requirements and they say "if the product vary in size or color, they are not to have separate numbers". I find this strange, because you SKU should be unique. Any help appreciated.

Edit - After some search, I came across the following useful articles In case this may help:

[Parent-Child-Relationships](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=200779220)

[SKU Basics dos and donts](http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/88529-Inventory-Labeling-Basics-SKUs-UPCs-EANs)

[SKU-construction-guidelines](http://www.andrewbrettwatson.com/index.php/help/187-sku-best-practices-for-online-shopping-sites)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly your sku can be whatever you want it to be.  Most businesses already have product identification numbers well before they have an online presence. If this is not the case, a simple solution is to use the barcodes on your products.  If you are not reselling anything, or don't have barcodes, your best bet is to just come up with a scheme you are comfortable with. All letters, numbers, and hyphens are valid sku parts.   You could simply start with 00001-A and go from there, where 00001 is the basic product type and the letter is representative of its configuration.

The sky is the limit.

BTW. Every product should have its own sku.  A Medium Blue T-Shirt and a Large Blue T-Shirt and a Large Blue T-Shirt should all have their own skus.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I agree. I am not sure why "they" suggested that color, etc. should not have different SKUs!

Comment: @NoChance I am not sure why "they" suggested that color, etc. should not have different SKUs!  . Once go through concept of configurable product you will get your answer. Its not necessary but its good practice.